# IE11 issue with transform rotateY and backface-visibilty hover effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having an issue with the code i am working on atm, works completely fine in Chrome and FF, but not in IE.

basically it is a simple hover effect where the game flips 180deg on the Y axis whilst hovering over it. backface visibility is set to hidden but it is not the case in IE. any ideas why? was thinking about introducing some jquery maybe to resolve issues with even older versions of IE..

---

HTML:

```
<div class="flip-container game">
                <div class="flipper">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="front">
                      <h1>
            Front
            </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                            <span class="game-title">
                                <h3>BACK</h3>
                                <span class="mob-icon"></span>
                            </span>

                            <button class="button green"><a href="#">Play Now</a></button>
                            <button class="blue button"><a href="#">More Info</a></button>
                    </div>

                </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

---

CSS:

```
   /*  do some flipping  */
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
    /* flip the pane when hovered */
    .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.05);
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
    }


.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 185px;
    height: 145px;
}

.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    background-color: #333;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background-color: #010b15;
    border: solid 2px #034baf;
}
```

FIDDLE - https://jsfiddle.net/Lcdrugvn/3/

Comment: I dont believe IE11 supports CSS 3d translate/rotate -  you can add ``-ms-transform`` manually but not sure if this will be 100% what you want

Answer (score 1):

found the solution -

```
/* do some flipping */

.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-container:hover .back {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }

.flip-container:hover .front {
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 320px;
    height: 480px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  width: 185px;
  height: 145px;
}

.front {
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  background-color: #333;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.back {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  background-color: #010b15;
  border: solid 2px #034baf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*  do some flipping  */
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
    /* flip the pane when hovered */
    .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.05);
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
    }

.flip-container:hover .back {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    .flip-container:hover .front {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 185px;
    height: 145px;
}

.flipper {
    transition: 0.4s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.4s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    background-color: #333;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background-color: #010b15;
    border: solid 2px #034baf;
}
```

try this, please adjust the transition timing

Comment: Thanks for this, definately a step in the right direction but the text is now reversed on the back pane after flipping also the issue i was getting initially in IE is happening in both chrome and FF.